# compare two tables using full outer join to highlight missing record from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

The first table, tblBasket is shown below,

```
 Code   ProductCode    Price
 SLK    ABC            20
 SLK    DEF            30
 SLK    GHI            40
```

The second table, tblOrders is shown below,

```
Code   ProductCode    SaleId     Amount
SLK    ABC            MMM        20
SLK    DEF            MMM        30
SLK    GHI            MMM        40
SLK    ABC            XXX        20
SLK    DEF            XXX        30
```

I need to check the tblBasket against tblOrders. The logic is that the basket is sold as a whole i.e. all 3 products with the code SLK must be sold together.

In the table tblOrder is a list of orders from different sales people (SaleId). Each SaleId where it has the code SLK should have the same 3 product codes as the basket. So in the above example saleId XXX is missing the product GHI. I need a query to flag this.

I tried the query below but it only return me 5 records it doesn't show me the missing product from saleId XXX even though I'm using a full outer join.

```
select * from tblBasket b full outer join tblOrders o
on b.Code = o.Code and b.ProductCode = o.ProductCode
```

Comment: What is your question?  What do you want the query to return?

Comment: All products appear in both tables. It will be in your result. You have incorrect statement copied or schema of tables are shown incorrectly. Which products is not in basket? Which basket is not in order?

Comment: apologies. Just realised that what I was thinking makes no sense. Will delete this post. Apologies again

Comment: @mHelpMe . . . The question is basically ok.  It just needs a question.  It is unclear what you want returned.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm just going through your post now, think that's probably what I'm after. Like I say just checking now

Comment: Do you want to show `XXX GHI` as missing?

Comment: yes I need to show that xxx GHI is missing

Answer (score 0):

You can summarize the data to get the number of expected and matching products for each sale.  Assuming that there are no duplicates in either table:

```
select sc.saleid, sc.code,
       count(*) as numProducts,
       count(o.productcode) as numMatchingProducts
from (select distinct saleid, code from tblOrders o) sc join
     tblBasket b
     on b.code = sc.code left join
     tblOrders o
     on o.saleid = sc.saleid and o.code = sc.code and
        b.productcode = o.productcode
group by sc.saleid, sc.code;
```

The logic is to generate the full combination of all products for each `saleid`.  Then, the `left join` determines whether or not the products in the order match the expected products.

You can then add a `having` clause if you want to get some subset of orders -- such as the complete ones, or the incomplete ones, or the ones missing one product.

Answer (score -1):

Do a left outer join from tblOrders to tblBaskets, joining on ProductCode.  If you just want the orders where its missing a product, simply add a "WHERE tblBaskets.ID IS NULL"